# Airflow not evaluating templated field, Error: Key has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores exclusively

Tags: airflow-2.x

I have a situation where I am querying data from some given set of tables. I do not know the size of the tables or how many rows I will query with each fetch until runtime. Structure is essentially this:

**Upstream DAG** acquires table names and determines size of tables/fetches. It then spawns multiple DAGs downstream through the TriggerDagRunOperator with respective variables to form a batch (most of this has been simplified in the below code).

**Downstream DAG** retrieves the variables from XCOM and uses them to form a Google Dataproc Serverless Batch (this is where the problem exists).

**Script** is called from the Dataproc Batch which reads from the sql DB and writes to a Google Storage Bucket.

### Upstream DAG

```
import datetime
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator


yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1), datetime.datetime.min.time())
cur_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')


# Define parent DAG args    `
default_dag_args = {
    # Setting start date as yesterday starts the DAG immediately when it is detected in the Cloud Storage bucket.
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    # If a task fails, retry it once after waiting at least 5 minutes
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'project_id': '{{ var.value.gcp_project }}',
    'region': '{{ var.value.gce_region }}',
}

# Define parent DAG
with models.DAG(
        dag_id='ai_dataproc_read_sql_upstream',
        # Run DAG once per day at 1:45pm
        schedule_interval='@once',
        max_active_tasks=3,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        default_args=default_dag_args
) as dag:
    
    # This section is simplified. The function results in a list containing table name, prim. key, fetch, and row count.
    table_list = [['TestTable', 'TestTableKey', 150000, 50000]]

    for table, column, table_row_count, fetch_size in table_list:
        processed = 0
        counter = 0

        while table_row_count - processed > 0:
            # Args to pass
            target_args = {'table': table.lower(),
                           'sort_col': column,
                           'fetch_size': fetch_size,
                           'offset': processed,
                           'iteration': counter}

            # This will spawn each subsequent DAG run
            trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
                task_id=f'{cur_date}_read_{table}_{counter}',
                trigger_dag_id='dataproc_read_sql_downstream',
                conf=target_args,
                dag=dag,
            )

            processed += fetch_size
            counter += 1
```

### Downstream DAG

```
import datetime
from airflow import models
from airflow.models import Connection
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators import dataproc
from airflow.decorators import task


@task(multiple_outputs=True)
def get_params_func(dag_run=None):

    return {'table': dag_run.conf['table'],
            'sort_col': dag_run.conf['sort_col'],
            'fetch': dag_run.conf['fetch_size'],
            'offset': dag_run.conf['offset'],
            'iteration': dag_run.conf['iteration']
            }


# Get connection info
conn = Connection.get_connection_from_secrets('QA Test')
yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1), datetime.datetime.min.time())

# Arguments to pass to Cloud Dataproc job.
default_dag_args = {
    # Setting start date as yesterday starts the DAG immediately when it is detected in the Cloud Storage bucket.
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    # If a task fails, retry it once after waiting at least 5 minutes
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'project_id': '{{ var.value.gcp_project }}',
    'region': '{{ var.value.gce_region }}',
}

with models.DAG(
        # DAG id needs to be the same as the trigger in the upstream file
        dag_id='dataproc_read_sql_downstream',
        schedule_interval='@once',
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
    # Push to XCOM
    dag_params = get_params_func()

    table = dag_params['table']
    sort_col = dag_params['sort_col']
    fetch = dag_params['fetch']
    offset = dag_params['offset']
    iteration = dag_params['iteration']

    # Params for Dataproc Batch
    pyspark_batch = {
        "pyspark_batch": {
            "main_python_file_uri": "gs://{{ var.value.gcs_script_bucket }}/read_sql.py",
            "jar_file_uris": [
                "gs://{{ var.value.gcs_jar_bucket }}/scala-compiler-2.13.0.jar",
                "gs://{{ var.value.gcs_jar_bucket }}/spark-snowflake_2.13-2.11.1-spark_3.2.jar",
                "gs://{{ var.value.gcs_jar_bucket }}/snowflake-jdbc-3.13.24.jar",
                "gs://{{ var.value.gcs_jar_bucket }}/mssql-jdbc-11.2.0.jre11.jar"
            ],
            "args": [
                conn.login,
                conn.password,
                conn.host,
                str(conn.port),
                'test',
                table,
                sort_col,
                str(fetch),
                str(offset),
                str(iteration)
            ],
        },
        "environment_config": {
            "execution_config": {
                "service_account": '{{ var.value.service_account }}',
                "network_tags": ['{{ var.value.network_tag1 }}', '{{ var.value.network_tag2 }}'],
                "subnetwork_uri": '{{ var.value.subnet_uri }}',
            },
        },
    }

    # Create a Cloud Dataproc cluster.
    create_dataproc_batch = dataproc.DataprocCreateBatchOperator(
        task_id=f"downstream_create_dataproc_{table}_{iteration}",  # This line is where the error is occurring
        batch_id=f"batch_create_sql_test_{table}_{iteration}",
        batch=pyspark_batch,
        region='{{ var.value.gce_region }}',
        dag=dag
    )

    # Delete Cloud Dataproc cluster.
    delete_dataproc_batch = dataproc.DataprocDeleteBatchOperator(
        task_id=f"downstream_delete_dataproc_{table}_{iteration}",
        batch_id=f"batch_create_sql_test_{table}_{iteration}",
        region='{{ var.value.gce_region }}',
        dag=dag
    )

    create_dataproc_batch >> delete_dataproc_batch
```

The task_id argument in DataprocCreateBarchOperator throws the following error:
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The key "downstream_create_dataproc_{ ti.xcom_pull(key='table') }_{ ti.xcom_pull(key='iteration') }" has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores exclusively

This should evaluate to "downstream_create_dataproc_testtable_0" for the first iteration, but airflow doesn't seem to be evaluating the template. I can size the upstream iteration down to 1 loop and take the templating out of the names and it runs just fine, which tells me the other templates in the script are fine...any ideas? Thanks in advance.

I've tried pre-generating the batch name from the upstream DAG as well as directly referencing the XCOM pull method.